# Php code to alphabetically sort a list from the database by clicking on a link on the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am relatively new to PHP and MySQL. I have a list of information I want to retrieve from the database and display on my html page. I want on one page to display the unordered list and then on the header of my html page to have links named like A | B | C.....and when I click on any of the alphabet letter to sort the first column of the unsorted list from the database according to the letter of the alphabet clicked.

Here is my code so far...

[My code so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CM0k.png)

This is how I want my page to look like...

[How I want my page to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGPvG.png)

I have googled about pagination using php and the results are helpful but not showing how to create pages for sorting a list based on a certain criteria, like alphabetically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do is, keep links on Alphabet letter as

```
 <a href="sort.php"> All </a> |
<a href="sort.php?let=A"> A </a> | 
<a href="sort.php?let=B"> B </a>
```

Now in your `sort.php` get the value sorted by query

First get sorting letter from url using `$_GET` variable

```
 <?php
      if(isset($_GET['let']))
       $let = $_GET['let'];
   else
   $let='';
     $query = "SELECT supplier, contact, telephone, email FROM suppliers WHERE supplier LIKE '$let%'";
     // other codes 
    ?>
```

Comment: I am new to PHP and MySQL and I am really getting excited even when a new page is opened using:

Comment: I am new to PHP and MySQL and I am really getting excited even when a new page is opened using:   <a href="sort.php"> All </a> |
<a href="sort.php?let=A"> A </a> | 
<a href="sort.php?let=B"> B </a>

Comment: I am sorry for the above comments, I wanted to use enter to go to another line. Anyway, I am new to PHP and MySQL and I am really getting excited even when a new page is opened using the href , however, using it only pops up a new empty page. It seems the sorting criteria is not working even after creating a sort.php . I want the query to sort the supplier table from the database depending on the alphabet letter selected.

Comment: It would be easy to debug code if you post code from sort.php here

Comment: } 


$result = mysql_query("SELECT supplier FROM suppliers");
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    $array[] = $row[1];
}
sort($array);
foreach ($array as $suppliers) {
   echo "$suppliers";
}

?>

Comment: Thanks a bunch Suman Sapkota, I finally understood your answer. The code worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SQL queries alone:

```
$letter = "A";
$query = "SELECT supplier, contact, telephone, email FROM suppliers WHERE supplier LIKE '$letter%'";
```

For your "ALL" page, just use a different SQL SELECT query omitting the LIKE from the query above

Comment: Thanks Phillip for your response. In my database, I have the supplier table which is the column on my html page that I want to sort. For instance, I have Microsoft, Coca Cola, Disney suppliers in my database. On my html page when I click the Alphabet letter A, there would be no result but when I click on the letter C, I would expect Coca Cola supplier to be listed there with the corresponding row values. I hope I am now more clearer.